# Change APK without changing version code in Internal Test Track

Tags: google-play-console

I started to use [Internal Test Track](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en). I created a test and a list of internal testers. Then I found something needed to fix and I fix it. So I want to deploy new APK but not want change APK version code. Can I do that? Can I just update APK version code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, even for internal test track changes you need to increase the version code.